# How to Pass Kotlin freeCompilerArgs via Command Line when executing a Gradle task?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

Context: This question pertains to an Android app's project that uses Jetpack Compose for UI, and primarily focuses on generating Compose compiler metrics through the command line.

---

My root project has gradle configured as follows:

```
subprojects {
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            // Trigger this with:
            // ./gradlew assembleRelease -PenableComposeReports=true
            if (project.findProperty("enableComposeReports") == "true") {
                freeCompilerArgs += ["-P", "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:reportsDestination=" + rootProject.buildDir.absolutePath + "/compose_metrics/"]
                freeCompilerArgs += ["-P", "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:metricsDestination=" + rootProject.buildDir.absolutePath + "/compose_metrics/"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute the `assembleRelease` gradle task with the following command:

`./gradlew assembleRelease -PenableComposeReports=true`, `freeCompilerArgs` are set up appropriately to generate Compose compiler metrics.

---

##### Now, I would like to know if it is possible to pass these `freeCompilerArgs` through CLI while executing the gradle task itself, without having any specific gradle configuration for generating Compose Compiler Metrics.

I am trying to build a CLI tool that generates Compose compiler metrics as part of its functionality, and I would like to be able to run it on any arbitrary Jetpack Compose project, regardless of whether gradle is configured to generate Compose compiler metrics (like above) or not.

---

Is it possible to pass these freeCompilerArgs via CLI?, Something like:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -Pkotlin.compiler.arguments="plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:reportsDestination=<path>”
```

If not, are there any alternative ways in which Compose Compiler Metrics could be generated via CLI for an arbitrary project (which may or may not have Gradle configured for generating the same)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem could be tackled using [Gradle Init scripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html).

> Initialization scripts (a.k.a. init scripts) are similar to other
> scripts in Gradle. These scripts, however, are run before the build
> starts.

So, we can execute a `gradle` `task` along with a `gradle` `init script`, which could configure `gradle` to enable generation of Compose compiler metrics.

---

```
// init.gradle
initscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2")
    }
}

allprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        tasks.configureEach {
            if (it.class.name.contains("org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile")) {
                kotlinOptions {
                    freeCompilerArgs += ["-P", "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:reportsDestination=" + rootProject.buildDir.absolutePath + "/reports/"]
                    freeCompilerArgs += ["-P", "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:metricsDestination=" + rootProject.buildDir.absolutePath + "/metrics/"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And execute the `gradle task` like `./gradlew assembleRelease -I init.gradle` to generate Compose compiler metrics.

---

After asking this question in multiple different threads, this is the only solution I've got so far for this particular problem.

Huge thanks to [Nikita Skvortsov](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/profiles/1283156041-Nikita-Skvortsov) for answering this question in an [another thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/11022871566610-Is-it-possible-for-a-plugin-to-configure-a-gradle-task-for-a-single-execution-), all credit to them for coming up with this solution. Also, thanks to [Björn Kautler](https://discuss.gradle.org/u/vampire/summary) for [helping me](https://gradle-community.slack.com/archives/CAHSN3LDN/p1681909169129029?thread_ts=1681906419.928959&cid=CAHSN3LDN) setup the `init.gradle` script appropriately.